# Convert a list of strings with characters into a calendar

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-re

I have this output:

```
'October 2022\nMo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su\n1\n€ 50\n2\n€ 50\n3\n€ 50\n4\n€ 50\n5\n€ 50\n6\n€ 50\n7
\n€ 50\n8\n€ 50\n9\n€ 50\n10\n€ 50\n11\n€ 50\n12\n€ 50\n13\n€ 50\n14\n€ 50\n15\n€ 50\n16
\n€ 50\n17\n€ 50\n18\n€ 50\n19\n—\n20\n—\n21\n—\n22\n—\n23\n—\n24\n€ 50\n25\n€ 50\n26\n€ 50\n27
\n€ 50\n28\n€ 50\n29\n€ 50\n30\n€ 50\n31\n€ 50\nNovember 2022\nMo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su\n1\n€ 50
\n2\n€ 50\n3\n€ 50\n4\n€ 50\n5\n€ 50\n6\n€ 50\n7\n€ 50\n8\n€ 50\n9\n€ 50\n10\n€ 50\n11
\n€ 50\n12\n€ 50\n13\n€ 50\n14\n€ 50\n15\n€ 50\n16\n€ 50\n17\n€ 50\n18\n€ 50\n19\n€ 50\n20
\n€ 50\n21\n€ 50\n22\n€ 50\n23\n€ 50\n24\n€ 50\n25\n€ 50\n26\n€ 50\n27\n€ 50\n28\n€ 50\n29
\n€ 50\n30\n€ 50\nApproximate prices in EUR for a 1-night stay\nMon 24 Oct - Sun 30 Oct (6-night stay)'
```

The numbers (n1,n2 etc.) are dates like 1-Oct-2022, 2-Oct-2022 and the other is the price for the corresponding date. How can I convert this into 2 list in order to have it as a DataFrame?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe use `split('\n')` or maybe it will need with double \ `split("\\n")`

Comment: how did you get this string? Maybe you should use different functions  to get it. If it was `<table>` then you should use `for`-loop to get every row separatelly, and later use another `for`-loop to get every item in row separatelly.